# search() function of Javascript does not behave properly

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework

I don't know why `search()` function returns 0 for any input with SPECIAL CHARACTER, I wanted to find position of 1st occurrence of special character. When I am hardcoding the value for `search()` method it is working fine, but when I am taking value from text box it is not working properly.

Following is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="return checkLength();"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Verify" onclick="getValue()"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Following is the script where I have implemented the use of `search()` of Javascript, but don't know why I am getting 0 value for any input. Actually I wanted to find the position of first special character occurrence.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btn').attr('disabled',true);

    $("#txt").bind({
        paste : function(){
            $('#btn').attr('disabled',false);
            checkLength();
        },
        cut : function(){
            checkLength();
        }
    });
});

function checkLength(){

    var txtLength = $("#txt").val().length;
    var banTxt = document.getElementById("txt").value;

    if (txtLength != 0) {

        if(isAlphaNumeric(document.getElementById("txt").value)) {
            $('#btn').attr('disabled',false);
        } else {


            var str=banTxt;
                          //Here I am using search() to find position of Special Character.
            var n=banTxt.search(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g);
            alert("position of special char is: " + n);


            var preTxt = banTxt.substring(0,(txtLength - 1));
            var preTxtLength = preTxt.length;
            alert("Special characters are not allowed!");
            if(preTxtLength == 0){
                $('#btn').attr('disabled',true);
                document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
            }else if(preTxtLength != 0){
                document.getElementById("txt").value = preTxt;
                $('#btn').attr('disabled',false);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $('#btn').attr('disabled',true);
    }
}

function isAlphaNumeric(inputString) {
    return inputString.match(/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/);
}

function getValue(){
    var txtValue = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    alert("Value submitted is: " + txtValue);
}
```

Comment: Please try to enter inputs like "123#4" (without quotes).

Comment: What value did you enter that gave unexpected results?

Comment: I tried with string with special characters like 123#4$5 , 12#4 , etc. and I am getting alert as position of special char is: 0

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var n=banTxt.search(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g);
> ```
>
> I tried with string with special characters like 123#4$5 , 12#4 , etc. and I am getting alert as position of special char is: 0

That's just what your regex matches: No alphabet characters and no blanks - that includes digits. In contrast, your `isAlphaNumeric` function matches against `/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/` - you probably want to align them with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have used the following line var n=banTxt.search(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g); for getting the position of special char, at the same time please note that i have used onkeyup event so if i am copy pasting the code i.e first <kbd>ctrl</kbd> then <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> itself is keyup event i think this might be the reason i am getting 0 as position of special char, as after pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> no text is pasted but onkeyup event is triggered.

I am looking for the solution of it.

Comment: If this is the answer to your question you should accept it. If it not the answer, you should edit this detail int the question and delete this answer.